# How to rollback everything to previous commit

Tags: git, git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently in a project with multiple people, a commit was made as seen in the image below. Marked in red you can see a commit with the description/comment of 'Merge?'.

This commit added numerous files and altered numerous others and was never intended to take place.

Using [atlassian-sourcetree](/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree) what do I need to do to roll everything back to the commit highlighted in blue? (I am 8 commits behind as seen in the screenshot.)

[image: sourcetree troubs]

Comment: I don't know about that program, but in git bash you can do `git reset --hard [the hash of the commit]`.

Comment: does 'hard' remove all other commits made after the 'bad commit'?

Comment: Yes, it will change everything back to the way it was just after the commit you pass it was made.

Comment: Nothing but garbage collection actually *removes* commits in git, but `git reset` moves a branch pointer, and once the commits are "beyond the tip of any branch", they become ripe for garbage collection.  (The branch's reflog keeps them around for a default expiration time of 30 days before they really get reaped.)  So they're effectively gone, but in emergencies you can "un-remove" them for a month or so.

Comment: Right click -> Reverse commit -> Push.  http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-undo-git-commit-in-sourcetree.html

Answer (score 106, accepted):

#### If you have pushed the commits upstream...

Select the commit you would like to roll back to and reverse the changes by clicking `Reverse File`, `Reverse Hunk` or `Reverse Selected Lines`. Do this for all the commits after the commit you would like to roll back to also.

[image: reverse stuff]
[image: reverse commit]

#### If you have not pushed the commits upstream...

Right click on the commit and click on `Reset current branch to this commit`.

[image: reset branch to commit]

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: The idea is the same. Feel free to fix it @Yeats

Comment: what next? after I resetted branch to the previous commit, it is asking me to pull everything back to the current version. I am not able to push anything

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Force push.

Comment: i tried that.. the gui had it grayed out.  The terminal din't work either

Comment: For anyone who has items in the SourceTree right-click menu greyed out: I restarted SourceTree and it went back to normal.

Comment: @Yeats This worked perfectly for me. I am using `Version 2.3.2`. The images are not exact yet the wording in the dropdown is the same.

Comment: In Aug 2020 still found this a useful 'quick' method for a small change in 1 file. Reverse commit or resetting the branch probably a better method overall though. Didn't see the option to 'reverse file' though (v.3.3.9).

Comment: One day you are in a hurry, you make a mistake, you look for a solution and someone from internet post exactly what you need perfectly explained. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 45):

I searched for multiple options to get my git reset to specific commit, but most of them aren't so satisfactory.

I generally use this to reset the git to the specific commit in source tree.

1. select commit to reset on sourcetree.
2. In dropdowns select the active branch , first Parent Only
3. And right click on "Reset branch to this commit" and select hard reset option (soft, mixed and hard)
4. and then go to terminal git push -f

You should be all set!

Comment: The answer is safe only **If you have not pushed the commits upstream**

Comment: The answer is **works** only if you have not pushed the commits upstream.

Comment: this answer also works after pushed commits upstream

Comment: This response provides a total rollback for commits done after a commit selected.

Answer (score 6):

There are two options to revert one commit our merged branch.

**A. Using sourcetree**

- Right click in commit
- Select reverse commit
- Sometimes, it can be failed. In that case, please try option B.

**B. Using terminal**

- Select your commit and look info on bottom side of screen. Example commit id: *1a6cd9879d8c7d98cdcd9da9cac8979dac7a89c*
- Click top right corner "*Terminal*" option of Sourcetree.
- Write in terminal: *git revert your_commit_id -m 1*
- When the commit message editor opens up:

  - For just accept and exit, write **:q** then click enter.
  - If you want to change the commit message, press "**i**", write your message and then write **:wq** click enter.

Answer (score 0):

If the master branch needs a Pull Request to accept changes (e.g. git flow and you can't git push force your changes), you can:

- Git clone a copy of your project
- Go to that new copy and checkout the commit you want to rollback to
- Go to the root folder of that commit in File Explorer
- Copy all files and folders except the .git folder
- Go to the original project and create a new branch from master
- Go to the root folder of that original project
- Remove all files and folders except the .git folder
- Paste all the files and folders from before
- Git add all changes and push to the new branch
- Do a PR for this branch to master